# python 3 prime number wrong answer yield why this code give me wrong prime factor like 9,21,.......?

Tags: python, yield, prime-factoring

```
primef = []
def i_prime(n) :
    count = 0
    for i in range ( 0, n ):
        for j in range ( 2, i ):
            if (not i % j == 0):
                yield i
                count += 1
            else:
                break


for i in i_prime(45):
    primef.append(i)
primefe = list(set(primef))
print(primefe)
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems be some flaw in your logic. What you have essentially made is an odd number generator (think about why). Since that part is already answered, here are some tips:

1. I would not suggest this algorithm to generate prime numbers as it
   is inefficient. You could alternatively cache all yielded prime
   numbers in a list and only check against that list instead of the
   `for j in range(2, i):`.
2. There is even more efficient way to generate prime numbers by
   utilizing a fact from number theory which states that all prime
   numbers greater than 3 are of the form `6k+1` or `6k+5` where k is an integer, which is non-negative for practical purposes (the explanation behind which is fairly simple).
   Here is a piece of code I wrote while solving a Project Euler question:

```
def is_prime(x: int) -> bool:
    if x <= 3:
        return x > 1
    elif x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        return False    
    
    i = 5
    while i*i <= x:
        if x % i == 0 or x % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
        i = i + 6
    
    return True
```

This prime checker served as a useful generator for me to find the 10001st prime number in 0.6s (for a Project Euler question).

Ask me any questions, if you have any, related to this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected version of your code - you need to go through all the possible factors before deciding that a number is not prime - you are `yield`ing the value as soon as there is one number that it does not divide by.

```
primef = []
def i_prime(n) :
    for i in range ( 0, n ):
        for j in range ( 2, i ):
            if (i % j == 0):
                break
        else:
            yield i


for i in i_prime(45):
    primef.append(i)
print(primef)
```

Comment: `primef = list(i_prime(45))`